# How to show selected values from database when edit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 for one of my fields. The data is perfectly inserting in the database. But when I want to edit the form, I need to fetch the data from the database. I can fetch the data but I don't know, how to show values in Select2 while editing the form.
This is the code when I am inserting the data in the database. The table name is "requests" and the column which stores the array is "crimes_section".

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label>Crime Section / جرم</label>
     <select class="crimeSections form-control" name="crimeSection[]" multiple="multiple" style="border-radius: 0px;" placeholder="35201-4578979-0">
         <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
         <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.crimeSections').select2({
   placeholder: "381, 392, 420"
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can't understand any thing where is the form you are editing ?
and what do you want to edit ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectedCrimes').select2({
    multiple: true,
    });
});
```

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assume below is the data received from the database.

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];
```

This is the one of the way to populate data into select box and by triggering change event you can able to set the default value.

```
$('#example').select2({
    data: data
}).val(1).trigger('change'); //This will set bug as selected value
```

Comment: how the selected values will shows in the input field when edit page load. where i have to put this code. thank you

Comment: Your problem is to set the selected value or populating the data into select box?

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two options together. set value to set from database using a hidden field

```
$('#sel_users').val(value);
$('#sel_users').select2().trigger('change');
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="selectedCrimes"> How this feild will show selected values data from database.

Comment: you can select the values from the database and add variable value to it like <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="selectedCrimes" value="<?php $selectedcrime ?>">

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Array.from(document.querySelector('.crimeSections').options).forEach(option=>{
if(option.value=="AL")
option.selected=true
});
```

Edit: Replace "AL" with value you wanna match